# How to bevel curved objects with many sharp turns?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I've created this lovely dolphin and would like to smooth the marked edge:
[image]

As soon as i try to apply the beevel-tool, things get out of hand really fast:
[image]

I tried to modify the bevel options but did not find anything that would help me. Is there a way to stop the beveled edges to overlap in the sharp areas or is there maybe another way to smooth the edge?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have concave profile it will create some bad faces, you need to add some edges across the top face:

[image]

Then the bevel will work (as long as it is not too large, otherwise faces will overlap, you can overlap but you'll need to fix the topology):

[image]